# Use mysqldump to export all databases into a file using DAYOFMONTH()

Tags: mysql

I would like to run a task in my cron to export all databases into a single file. I would like to create 1 file for every day of the week (e.g. `all_[1-7].sql`). And I'd like it to replace the previous file if it exists. Is it possible to use MySQL's date and time functions e.g.:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppass –all-databases | gzip > /backups/mysql/all_`DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE())`.sql.gz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. What comes after the pipe character runs a shell command, not MySQL. Therefore you need to generate the date "the shell way". E.g.

```
... | gzip > /backups/mysql/all_`date +%u`.sql.gz
```

Comment: Common behavior is to overwrite, but on certain cases (e.g. zsh) you need to take an extra step to enable overwrite.